# How to do multiprocessing for list of values?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

- I have list in python having 1000 values
- Each value has to process separately
- How to do the process independently
- Here question is regarding multiprocessing or independent process

my current code

```
import mysql.connector
for each in value_list:
   
# Connecting to the Database
   mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
   host ='localhost',
   database ='College',
   user ='root',
    )
   cs = mydb.cursor()
  
   # drop clause
   statement ="UPDATE STUDENT SET AGE = 23 WHERE Name=each"
  
   cs.execute(statement)
   mydb.commit()
  
   # Disconnecting from the database
   mydb.close()
```

My above code will process one by one. since each update is independent of another how to achieve using multiprocessing

Is there any way to use like `from joblib import Parallel, delayed`

Comment: The update statement can go In parallel if the Name column is an index, or I'm wrong?

You should consider create index in Name.

Comment: If you want to use multiprocessing then start some processes (you decide on how many you think you need) where each process consumes data from a queue then performs the SQL based on that. Once your list has been exhausted, terminate the processes

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how this could be done using multiprocessing.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import mysql.connector as MYSQL

NPROCS = 5

value_list = [] # List of names to be updated

CONFIG = {
    'host': 'localhost',
    'user': 'root',
    #'passwd': 'secret',
    'database': 'College'
}

def process(queue):
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = MYSQL.connect(**CONFIG)
        while param := queue.get():
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            sql = f'UPDATE STUDENT SET AGE=23 WHERE Name="{param}"'
            cursor.execute(sql)
            cursor.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        if conn:
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()

def main():
    queue = Queue()
    procs = [Process(target=process, args=(queue,)) for _ in range(NPROCS)]
    for p in procs:
        p.start()
    for each in value_list:
        queue.put(each)
    for _ in range(NPROCS):
        queue.put(None)
    for p in procs:
        p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: why we need to p.join(), is that required?

Comment: @sim join() waits for the process to terminate and is good practice